Error sending confirmation email: Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"
I am working with node.js and tried sending email via Nodemailer but  I'm getting this error:

Missing credentials for "PLAIN" I have a function for registering also with successful registering there will be an email to the gmail account added
Any help would be appreciated. Im stuck in this code for a while now


// Configure your email transport using SMTP or another method
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  host: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL_USER, // Your email address
    pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS, // Your email password or app password
  },
  authMethod: "PLAIN", // Specify authentication method explicitly
});

// Function to send registration confirmation email
const sendConfirmationEmail = async (name, email) => {
  try {
    const mailOptions = {
      to: email,
      from: "TESTING <induseducationworld@gmail.com>", // Your verified sender email
      subject: "Registration Confirmation for Demo Class",
      html: `
        <p>Dear ${name},</p>
        <p>Thank you for registering for the demo class.</p>
        <p>We will contact you with further details soon.</p>
        <p>Best regards,</p>
        <p>Your Company</p>
      `,
    };

    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log(`Confirmation email sent to ${email}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending confirmation email:", error);
    throw error; // Rethrow the error to handle it in the caller function
  }
};


  



